# Window Hangs And Freezes [SDL 2]

Tags: c++, windows, sdl-2

I have a text file full of information on where to place tiles in a game i'm making, the fastest way to access this information is with a for loop. But whenever i use the for loop to get through all the information it freezes the program for about 12 seconds, in those 12 i cant move the window, nothing on the renderer updates/is drawn, and then when i click on the window it breaks and says "*window name* (Not Responding)". I tried using a while loop but it still does the same thing.

How can i loop through bigger numbers (there are about 4,000 tiles in the level) without the program freezing/hanging on me? I'm just using SDL 2, no OpenGL involved.

```
    int tiles = 4000;
    int x[4000];
    int y[4000];
    tile obj[4000];

    for(int i = 0; i < tiles; i++)
    {


    x[i] = txt.x;
    y[i] = txt.y;

    obj[i].Load(x[i], y[i]);
    obj[i].Add();

    SDL_RenderClear(ren);
    LoadScreen();
    SDL_RenderPresent(ren);
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create another thread.

It's good idea to wait for all data to load before starting game, so during load, you don't need to render anything. Even with this approach, it is better to use another thread and don't keep "UI Thread" busy. During load time your UI would be mostly disabled except a cancel button that will stop loading thread.

```
#include <process.h>

bool bReady;

void LoadTiles(void* pArg)
{
    // Load Data here
    *((int*)pArg) = 0;
    ///////////////////

    bReady = true;
}

void main()
{
    btnStart.SetEnabled(false);
    bReady = false;

    int iTarget;
    uintptr_t hLoadingThread = _beginthread(LoadTiles, 0, &iTarget);

    while (true) // usually you pick a message here
    {
        if (bReady)
            btnStart.SetEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

This is just a very simple example, multi-threading needs a lot of work and study!